# How can I find the gradient of this function? $f(r,t)=r^3\cos(t).$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, interpolation

$$f(r,t)=r^3\cos(t).$$
Is it not like this: $<3r^2,-\sin(t)>$

Comment: The cos $t$ term doesn't disappear - think of it as multiplying $r^3$ by a constant when computing the partial derivative WRT r

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to compute the *first partial* derivatives of $f(r,t)$ to find the gradient. For example, your first component will be $3r^2\cos(t),$ not just $3r^2,$ since partial differentiation with respect to $r$ treats any other variable ($t$ in particular) as a constant. Likewise, you'll need to fix your second component.

Comment: Oh, So it would be like what someone commented above. Like <3r^2cos(t),-r^3sin(t)> Keeping one constant the deriving the other one.

Comment: Precisely right.

Answer (score 2):

may be $<3r^2\cos t,-r^3\sin t>$

Comment: @gaoxinge.. "it is"